# Web Application hosted in IIS cannot conect to MongoDB from same server

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, iis, database-connection, web-deployment

the mongodb is running in the server, and i have put as bind ip the server's ip (is not the localhost) in the mongo configuration file.
My web api in asp.net core , perform the database calls in example as the following (i didnt put the real ip in the code snippet but is different than 127.0.0.1) :

```
        const string MONGO_URL = "mongodb://xx.xxx.x.xxx:27017";

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(MONGO_URL));

        [Route("")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
        {

            var client = new MongoClient(settings);
            var userName = User.Identity.Name;

            var filter = Builders<MongoCartDto>.Filter.Eq("Username", userName);

            var database = client.GetDatabase("myDatabase");

            var collection = database.GetCollection<myDto>("myEntity");

            var queryResult = collection.Find(filter);

            if (queryResult.CountDocuments() != 0)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, queryResult.First());
            else
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

       }
```

When i run the project locally (with vpn connection), the mongo db connection is successful. But when is deployed in the same server with IIS, the web api dont "see" the database .

Comment: To find the root cause, you need to dig the exception. First of all , please check your event viewer. If there is any exception thrown from .net core runtime, you will find it.  If no exception can be found in event viewer. It might be a first chance exception. Then you need to collect dump file with debug diagnostic collection and analyze the dump file with WINDBG. [Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919791/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-b)